# Pull says there are changes, stash says there are no changes?

Tags: git

> I:\work\bitbucket\repos\proj1 [work2]> git pull
>   Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org':
>   error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>           proj1/App_Data/proj1Db_Data.mdf
>           proj1/App_Data/proj1Db_Log.ldf
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
>   Aborting
>   I:\work\bitbucket\repos\proj1 [work2]> git stash
>   No local changes to save
>   I:\work\bitbucket\repos\proj1 [work2]>
>
> I:\work\bitbucket\repos\proj1 [work2]> git status
>   `# On branch work2
>   '# Your branch and 'origin/work2' have diverged,
>   '# and have 2 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean

Very confusing...
I have tried using

> git update-index --assume-unchanged

on the .mdf/.ldf files, but that didn't help.
What am I overlooking?

Comment: Looks like I needed to use '--no-assume-unchanged' to get the db files back in synch.

Answer (score 3):

Can be if those files are not tracked in your local branch and are tracked in remote - you can't stash them, but they will be overwritten.

But more likely is there are line endings problems.